# Table Placement Issue

Tags: tables, positioning, article

I am using a template I found and it usually gives me no problems, but I am having an issue with table placement. I am trying to print four tables on the last page of my document, but the fourth one keeps moving to another page even though there is plenty of room for it on the page prior. How can I fix this?

(A few comments- apologies in advance for the formatting- couldn't figure out how to block paste text so the indentations are messed up. Also, I know there are a lot of extras that I don't need for what is included here, but there is nothing I would like to remove from the code at this time.)

Thanks in advance!

```
\documentclass[11pt, a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[inner=2cm,outer=2cm,top=2.5cm,bottom=2.5cm]{geometry}
\pagestyle{empty}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{fancyhdr, lastpage, bbding, pmboxdraw}
\usepackage[usenames,dvipsnames]{color}
\definecolor{darkblue}{rgb}{0,0,.6}
\definecolor{darkred}{rgb}{.7,0,0}
\definecolor{darkgreen}{rgb}{0,.6,0}
\definecolor{red}{rgb}{.98,0,0}
\usepackage[colorlinks,pagebackref,pdfusetitle,urlcolor=darkblue,citecolor=darkblue,linkcolor=darkred,bookmarksnumbered,plainpages=false]{hyperref}
\renewcommand{\thefootnote}{\fnsymbol{footnote}}
\pagestyle{fancyplain}
\fancyhf{}
\lhead{ \fancyplain{}{MAT 135} }
\rhead{ \fancyplain{}{March 5, 2019} }
\thispagestyle{plain}
\usepackage{listings}
\usepackage{caption}
\DeclareCaptionFont{white}{\color{white}}
\DeclareCaptionFormat{listing}{\colorbox{gray}{\parbox{\textwidth}{#1#2#3}}}
\captionsetup[lstlisting]{format=listing,labelfont=white,textfont=white}
\usepackage{verbatim}
\usepackage{fancyvrb}
\usepackage{acronym}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{multicol}
\VerbatimFootnotes
\definecolor{OliveGreen}{cmyk}{0.64,0,0.95,0.40}
\definecolor{CadetBlue}{cmyk}{0.62,0.57,0.23,0}
\definecolor{lightlightgray}{gray}{0.93}
\lstset{
basicstyle=\ttfamily,
keywordstyle=\color{OliveGreen},
commentstyle=\color{gray},
numbers=left,
numberstyle=\tiny,
stepnumber=1,
numbersep=5pt,
backgroundcolor=\color{lightlightgray},
frame=none,
tabsize=2,
captionpos=t,
breaklines=true,
breakatwhitespace=false,
showspaces=false,
showtabs=false,
columns=flexible,
morekeywords={__global__, __device__},
}
\begin{document}
\begin{center}
{\Large{Sections 4.2 and 4.3 Questions}}
\end{center}
\begin{center}
March 5, 2019
\end{center}
\vspace{5mm}
\noindent 1. Consider the functions $f(x)=x^2$ and $g(x)=\sqrt{x}$ on the interval $(0,\infty)$. Compare their slopes.
\vspace{5mm}
\noindent 2. Define concave upward and concave downward.
\vspace{5mm}
\newpage
\begin{table}[h]
  \begin{center
\begin{tabular}{|c|c|c|c|}
  \hline
  \textbf{f''(x)} & - & 0 & +\\
  \hline
  \textbf{f'(x)} & decreasing & horizontal tangent & increasing\\
  \hline
  \textbf{f(x)} & concave down & inflection point & concave up\\
  \hline
\end{tabular}
  \end{center}
\end{table}
\begin{table}[h]
  \begin{center}
\begin{tabular}{|c|c|c|c|}
  \hline
  \textbf{f'(x)} & - & 0 & +\\
  \hline
  \textbf{f(x)} & decreasing & horizontal tangent & increasing\\
  \hline
\end{tabular}
  \end{center}
\end{table}
\begin{table}[h]
  \begin{center}
  \caption{Identifying Inflection Points of $f$ Based on The Sign of $f''$}
\begin{tabular}{|c|c|c|c|}
  \hline
  & c & & \\
  \hline
  - & & + & inflection point\\
  \hline
  - & & - & not an inflection point\\
  \hline
  + & & - & inflection point\\
  \hline
  + & & + & not an inflection point\\
  \hline
\end{tabular}
  \end{center}
\end{table}
\begin{table}[h]
  \begin{center}
  \caption{Classifying Local Extrema of $f$ Based on the Sign of $f'$
\begin{tabular}{|c|c|c|c|}
  \hline
  & c & & \\
  \hline
  - & & + & local minimum\\
  \hline
  - & & - & not local extremum\\
  \hline
  + & & - & local maximum\\
  \hline
  + & & + & not local extremum\\
  \hline
\end{tabular}
  \end{center}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 4):

The immediate cause of the issue you describe is that you have four `table` environments, while the `article` document class by default only allows up to three such environments to be placed on a single page. That's why the fourth `table` gets pushed to the next page.

One way to solve this issue is to issue the instructions

```
\setcounter{totalnumber}{4}
\setcounter{topnumber}{4}
\setcounter{bottomnumber}{4}
```

in the preamble. Of course, if you find yourself needing to place 7 (presumably very small, right?) `table` environments on a single page, you should change the above to

```
\setcounter{totalnumber}{7}
\setcounter{topnumber}{7}
\setcounter{bottomnumber}{7}
```

Incidentally, I can't help but remark that the overall quality of your LaTeX is far from perfect. For sure, the code contains two syntax errors -- `\begin{center` and  `\caption{Classifying Local Extrema of $f$ Based on the Sign of $f'$`; can you spot the missing curly braces? -- which *must* be fixed before the document can be compiled. And writing `\textbf{f''(x)}`, `\textbf{f''(x)}`, and`\textbf{f''(x)}` is bound to raise more than a few eyebrows, and it might even cause some readers' eyes to bleed profusely. Do please consider writing `$\mathbf{f}''(\mathbf{x})}$`, `$\mathbf{f}'(\mathbf{x})}$`, and `$\mathbf{f}(\mathbf{x})}$` instead.

Comment: Thanks- I did not know this about the article document class! These errors your noticed only occurred when I inputted my code here- they are not present in my document.

Comment: @MathStudent1324 - Setting the `totalnumber` counter to `3` is not limited to the `article` document class. Many other document classes also feature this setting.

Comment: Also, use `\centering`  inside the table environment. The `center` environment adds unwanted vertical spacing.